# display all results after foreach php loop not just last result

Tags: php, foreach

this is my first post to this forum, I realise a similar question has been asked many times and i can promise you I have tried most of them to adapt to my situation over the last two weeks.
I need to show all results from foreach loop out of the function but it will only show the last loop result.

this is the html source it returns

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1005
            [1] => ABC
            [2] => 601005
        )

)
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1010
            [1] => DEF
            [2] => 601010
        )

)
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1015
            [1] => FGH
            [2] => 601015
        )

)
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1020
            [1] => XYZ
            [2] => 601020
        )

)
outside of loop Array

Room 1

Room 2

Room 3

Room 4
(
            [0] => 1020
            [1] => XYZ
            [2] => 601020
)
```

Comment: Personally, i'd skip dumping each element and dump the whole array.  Typically makes it more obvious what's going on; chances are, your array has other entries in it that contain at least one of the other rows.

Comment: have you tried putting your all `print_r()`s inside the `foreach` so that it would print everything while the process is on going?

Comment: just updated code to show all of it , I am getting all the array results I am expecting. The problem is that I need all 4 results to pass to another page.

Answer (score 2):

`$currentRoom` never changes so you're always writing to `$codearray[""]`, each iteration overwrites the result of the previous iteration.

Do something like: (`$key` instead of `$currentRoom`)

```
$codearray[$key] = array($roomcode[$currentRoom][0], $ratecode[$currentRoom][0], $rateaccesscode[$currentRoom][0]);
```

Comment: The big question, though: if `$currentRoom` never changes, how does `$codearray[4]` have a value?

Comment: @cHao magic? OP probably left out some (important) code.

Comment: Probably.  There's definitely something wacky going on in the code that's not here.

Comment: add all the code to make it clearer